# Heroku is not dectecting Node.js buildpacks

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, terminal, hyper

I am using Heroku and trying to deploy my code, but when I try to deploy I get an error.

It says it does not detect any build packs, but I have done a version check and have the latest Node.js installed.

Is there something I am missing?

terminal:

```
Creating app... done, ⬢ boiling-lake-07398
https://boiling-lake-07398.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/boiling-lake-07398.git
Shons-MacBook-Pro:Newsletter-Signup shonswope$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 1305, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1305/1305), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1248/1248), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1305/1305), 1.87 MiB | 455.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1305 (delta 179), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this a
pplication automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to pacific-bastion-08294.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/pacific-bastion-08294.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/pacific-bastion-08294.git'
Shons-MacBook-Pro:Newsletter-Signup shonswope$ npm --version
6.12.0
Shons-MacBook-Pro:Newsletter-Signup shonswope$ node --version
v12.13.0
Shons-MacBook-Pro:Newsletter-Signup shonswope$ git --version
git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
Shons-MacBook-Pro:Newsletter-Signup shonswope$
```

Answer (score 0):

Still, following the [documentation mentioned](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) in the error message, try and set a buildpack explicitly:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
```

> This situation may also occur if you remove or rename a file that previously led to the automatic detection of your application type and thus the automatic setting of the detected buildpack on your application.

Check also [the answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43362014/6309), and your [`package.json` content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41154473/6309).
As [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39644260/6309), that `package.json` and `Procfile` must be at the root folder of your project.